# Completely building a web app with static file and AJAX calls

Tags: ajax, rest, asynchronous, static

I'm considering building a new web app with totally with static "html, js, css" file and

make asynchronous call (AJAX) to gain access to DB, some calculations and handle sessions.

So the static files will have basic DOM structures and css applied form only at the beginning

and static js code will asynchronously communicate with server to show page contents

dynamically.

What would be good and bad points of making a web app like this?

and do you recommend or not recommend this way of developing a web app?

Comment: That approach has worked well for me in multiple apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have built a a decent sized web site with this pattern. I feel that this is the current method of developing sites as there are no page post-backs. A fully AJAX site is more 'Web 2.0', if you will.

Debugging can be harder with this setup, but if you're careful (which isn't that hard to do with a brand new site), it shouldn't cause you too much headache. I would recommend you go this route.

Comment: How did handle with session in that case?

Comment: We used the Spring framework and the MVC pattern, so all of our AJAX requests went through controllers and the framework handled the session. I would recommend Spring if you can use Java.